# django - apscheduler how to keep job when uwsgi restart

Tags: django, apscheduler

django - 2.2.12

apscheduler - 3.6.3

I would like to set the notification to be sent two weeks after the user executes a specific task.

scheduler.py

```
import logging
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class JobLauncher:

    _sched = None

    def __init__(self):
        JobLauncher._sched = BackgroundScheduler()
        JobLauncher._sched.start()

    def __str__(self):
        return "JobLauncher"

    def run(self, job):
        return self.run_job(job)

    def stop(self, job):
        JobLauncher._sched.remove_job(job.name)

    def shutdown(self):
        if JobLauncher._sched.running():
            logger.debug('Scheduler is shutting down.')
            JobLauncher._sched.shutdown()
        else:
            logger.warn("Cannot shutdown scheduler because scheduler is not running at the moment. please check scheduler status.")

    def run_job(self, job):
        if JobLauncher._sched.get_job(job.name) is None:
          _job = JobLauncher._sched.add_job(func=job.runMethod, trigger='date', id=job.name, args=job.job_params,run_date = job.job_date)
          return True
        return False

class CommonJob:

    def __str__(self):
        return "Job Infos : {name : %s, job_params : %s}" % (self.name, self.job_params)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
      
    @name.setter 
    def name(self, new_name):
        self._name = new_name
      
    @property
    def job_date(self):
        return self._job_date
    
    @job_date.setter 
    def job_date(self, new_job_date):
        self._job_date = new_job_date
       
    @property
    def job_params(self):
        return self._job_params   
        
    @job_params.setter 
    def job_params(self, new_job_params):
        self._job_params = new_job_params
        
    @property
    def runMethod(self):
        return self._runMethod
    
    @runMethod.setter 
    def runMethod(self, new_runMethod):
        self._runMethod = new_runMethod
    


class JobLauncherHolder:

    _launcher = None

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        if not JobLauncherHolder._launcher:
            JobLauncherHolder._launcher = JobLauncher()

        return JobLauncherHolder._launcher
```

Add Job Code

```
from utils.scheduler import JobLauncherHolder,CommonJob

def event(self,userUID):
    launcher = JobLauncherHolder.getInstance()
    if launcher:
       job = CommonJob()
       job.name = str(userUID) + 'alarm'
       date =  datetime.now()  + timedelta(days=14)
       job.job_date = date
       job.runMethod = self.testAlarm
       job.job_params = [userUID]
       launcher.run(job)

def testAlarm(self,userUID):
    sendTestFCM(userUID)
```

change it after 20 seconds instead of 14 days as the test code and run it, will receive a notification normally.

But when I changed it after 3 minutes and run `sudo service uwsgi restart`, the job does not run. In order to use it in the actual service, the job must be maintained even if it is restarted for updates.

i tried store redis

```
 def __init__(self):
        jobstores = {
        'default': RedisJobStore(jobs_key='dispatched_trips_jobs', 
        run_times_key='dispatched_trips_running', host='localhost', port=6379)
        }
        JobLauncher._sched = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)
        JobLauncher._sched.start()
```

raise error

```
File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
 File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 116, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./post/views.py", line 826, in scheduleTest
    launcher.run(job)
  File "./utils/scheduler.py", line 30, in run
    return self.run_job(job)
  File "./utils/scheduler.py", line 44, in run_job
    _job = JobLauncher._sched.add_job(func=job.runMethod, trigger='date', id=job.name, args=job.job_params,run_date = job.job_date)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 443, in add_job
    self._real_add_job(job, jobstore, replace_existing)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 867, in _real_add_job
    store.add_job(job)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/redis.py", line 82, in add_job
    self.pickle_protocol))
TypeError: can't pickle uwsgi._Input objects
```

Please tell me the best way to keep the job while restarting `uwsgi`. `memory` `redis` `mysql` can use three methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pickle error happens because you're trying to add a persistent job that contains an unserializable object (`uwsgi._Input` in this case) among its arguments. This can sometimes happen inadvertently when the scheduled function is in fact an instance method and the instance contains an unserializable object.

To resolve this, you need to check the arguments you are passing to the job to see if any of them contain `uwsgi._Input` objects. Make sure you also check the target function. If it's an instance method, make sure the instance does not contain such objects as members either.